# Redux ajax workflow with prelogic

Tags: ajax, reactjs, reactjs-flux, redux

I'm writing a restful redux/react app. 
My desired output is such.

```
INPUT_CHANGE-->
(state = {valid: false})->REDUCER->(state = {valid: true})-->
AJAX CALL
```

From the redux documentation, async javacript is supposed to be called from the action creator, but I don't understand how to get to the action creator once the state changes from valid:false to valid:true.

Since this is a react app, I could change a hidden input called valid, which has an onChange action creator attached to it, but this seems like an unneccessary extra step. Any ideas?

Comment: Something must be listening to the valid state change. Wherever that is, you can use `componentWillUpdate` to fire an action creator which does the async stuff.

Comment: With redux, do the components technically update? I thought the point was to rerender with new props?

Comment: Right exactly... whenever component is about to re-render with new props `componentWillUpdate` is going to fire.. The general point is that something that's observing state changes (like a connected component) needs to fire an action (like an ajax call)

Comment: Alright, that makes sense to me! Cheers

Comment: Beware of infinite loops though! Remember that you should only dispatch more state changes under certain conditions. It's tempting to just dispatch whenever state changes, but state changes state changes state, so just keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

My general preference is to have the action creators handle all async operations. So the validation operation in this question is comparable to the `shouldFetchPosts` function in http://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

The action creator would then be something like `inputChangeAndSubmitIfValid` which corresponds to that file's `fetchIfNeeded` action creator.

On very rare occasions I implement an [observer](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/303#issuecomment-125184409) for catching store changes, but I always try to find a better action oriented way first.